# How to create unique_ptr with static deleter

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I would like to have a member function unique-ptr with a static deleter function where the function is known at compiletime and no function pointer is required at allocation. I do not know if it is possible but [this test](https://godbolt.org/z/zPcz7o677) confuses me:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Apa {
    std::string name;

    ~Apa() {
        std::cout << name << " deleted\n";
    }
};

static void staticDeleter(Apa *a) {
    std::cout << "static deleter\n";
    delete a;
}

int main() {
    auto deleter = [] (Apa *a) {
        std::cout << "deleter\n";
        delete a;
    };

    {
        // This is what I want but as a member of a struct
        auto ptr1 = std::unique_ptr<Apa, decltype(deleter)>{new Apa{"Apan"}}; // <----------------

        std::cout << sizeof(ptr1) << " -> Apan\n";
    }
    
    {
        auto ptr2 = std::unique_ptr<Apa, decltype(&staticDeleter)>(new Apa{"Beata"}, staticDeleter);
           // When trying to omit this argument this line does not compile ------------^

        std::cout << sizeof(ptr2) << " -> Beta\n";
    }
}
```

This results in the output

```
8 -> Apan
deleter
Apan deleted
16 -> Beta
static deleter
Beata deleted
```

So unless there is some unknown compiler magic, the size of the pointers indicate that it is in fact possible to create a unique ptr with static deleter function.

When trying to do the same thing inside a struct

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Apa{

};

struct Container {
    using deleter = decltype((Apa*) {}); // Edit: This was a typo: se below

    std::unique_ptr<Apa, deleter> ptr  ;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(Container::ptr) << "\n";
}
```

The output `16` shows that the unique_ptr does want a pointer to the deleter function.

Is there any way to make this work so that I define a unique_ptr with a custom deleter function inside a class that is statically defined instead of specified at runtime?

### Edit:

After some feedback from @eerorika i realized that the code actually works if the lambda is written correctly. [Working code](https://godbolt.org/z/7e9hf86hE):

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Apa{
    ~Apa() {
        std::cout << "Apa deleted\n";
    }
};

struct Container {
    using deleter = decltype([](Apa* apa) {
        std::cout << "deleter\n";
        delete apa;
    });

    std::unique_ptr<Apa, deleter> ptr = std::unique_ptr<Apa, deleter>{new Apa} ;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(Container::ptr) << "\n";

    Container container{};
}
```

Yields output:

```
8
deleter
Apa deleted
```

Comment: Is this for a *pimpl pattern* (pointer to implementation), or for hooking in some additional behavior during destruction (e.g., destruction notification to listeners), debugging helper, or something else?

Comment: Its for wrapping a c library and not having to specify the destructor function manually.

Comment: Ahh, nice!  Good use of a smart pointer to manage foreign object lifetimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> using deleter = decltype((Apa*) {});
> ```

This is an unnecessarily convoluted way of writing:

```
using deleter = Apa*;
```

The type `Apa*` doesn't satisfy the requirement that `std::unique_ptr` imposes on its deleter because `Apa*` isn't a FunctionObject. The example program is ill-formed (at least if you try to create an instance of it). Hence, it doesn't matter what size the object is.

> Is there any way to make this work so that I define a unique_ptr with a custom deleter function inside a class that is statically defined instead of specified at runtime?

Your lambda example works since C++20. You can define similar deleter as a class, which works with earlier versions as well. For example:

```
struct deleter {
    void operator()(Apa* ptr) {
        std::cout << "custom deleter\n";
        delete ptr;
    }
};

struct Container {
    std::unique_ptr<Apa, deleter> ptr  ;
};
```

Comment: Realized now that my lambda syntax only works in c++20, your struct syntax seems to work for older versions as well

Comment: @Lasersköld Oh, yea. It relies on default initialisation of the deleter and lambdas weren't default initialisable prior to C++20.